# CordovaCamera always a Square photo?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

What do I have to change so CordovaCamera doesn't make Square photos anymore?

Now when I call this code:

```
 var options = {
          quality: 100,
          destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
          sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
          allowEdit: true,
          encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
          // targetWidth: 1600,
          // targetHeight: 1280,
          popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
          saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
          correctOrientation:true
        };

          $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (imageData) {
              $scope.imgURI = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
```

It opens the Camera, you take the photo, then you get a screen where you see a Square. When you say "use photo" it saves the picture part that was inside the square..

Answer (score 10):

If you use `allowEdit: true,`, after taking the picture it goes to the crop screen, and the crop screen always crops a square.

If you don't want a square then use `allowEdit: false,` and you'll use the original image with the original size.

Comment: Trying but crop rectangle is free to do anything. square and rectangle

Comment: @PareshGami iOS or Android? iOS used to be a rectangle, Android a square, but on Android it launchs an intent to cropping/photo editing apps installed, so some of them might allow square, circle, rectangle or freeform, I think the recommended is google photos

Comment: Yes google plus crop is working with square. Thanks for that

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
After a bit more research I can see this actually still asks you to crop the image. In my apps I have always wanted to square image so it has not yet been an issue for me.

Maybe you could look into this post on the Ionic forum which seems to have a few suggestions on how to fix the issue.

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/cordova-camera-crop/14661/7

---

**ORIGINAL:** 
You have the targetWidth and targetHeight variables commented out. If you uncomment those lines, and then set each one to the height and width in pixels.

For example the code below would try and get a target width of a 1080p image (1920px by 1080px)

```
var options = {
      quality: 100,
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
      allowEdit: true,
      encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      targetWidth: 1920,
      targetHeight: 1080,
      popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
      correctOrientation:true
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change below code in .java file which is located here

**platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\camera\CameraLauncher.java** **after line number 436**

```
  cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
  cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
  cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
  cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 700);
  cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 700);
  cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
```